# Вырезать подстроку

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Есть строки вида:

```
/city/ufa/val1/

/city/kazan/val2/val3/
```

Необходимо взять последнее слово из строки, т.е. от предпоследнего `/` до последнего `/` (Например: в первом случае это 'val1', а во втором случае 'val3'). Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: `basename($path)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

вариант 1.

> [`basename()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.basename.php) — Возвращает последний компонент имени из указанного пути

```
print basename("/city/kazan/val2/val3/");
```

вариант 2.

```
print array_pop(explode('/', trim($path, '/')))
```

вариант 3

```
preg_match("~/([\w+]+)/$~", $path, $matches);
print $matches[1];
```

вариант 4

```
print ltrim(strrchr(rtrim($path,'/'),'/'),'/');
```